# The Sea of Shadow before the 3rd Maelstrom

Tags: world-of-darkness, wraith-the-oblivion

What would be the dangers of entering/falling or navigating the Sea of Shadows prior the 3rd Maelstom?

Also, a vampire that could fall into the Sea of Shadows would suffer what kind of pain/damage (mentally and physically)?

Comment: I have to imagine that the "Sea of Shadows" sourcebook would have the information. I don't have it to hand, but that might be a good place to start.

Comment: The book Sea of Shadows book does not have all of that info because it was written for modern times, after third maelstrom.

Comment: True, but I thought it might also have the history of the Tempest as a whole. I know I've seen it somewhere, but I'll have to keep looking.

Comment: @Jadasc On the core book the history section tells how the sunless sea evolves to tempest. But I think Daniel is looking for more concrete information.

Comment: That's a question I would like to see answered. I storytelled a story of Dark Ages: Wraith, and I found hard to imagine the Sea of Shadow that times. Unfortunately Wraith players are very few and these questions tend to have few if any answers. I have put a bounty to see if that stimulates an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find an official answer but here's how I would homebrew it.

**Wraiths**

Every hour take 1 aggravated damage. If the player runs out of corpus they have to fight their shadow but the shadow gets 3 additional dots to spend (the storyteller could make it be for only that fight or forever). You could justify the player waking up in oblivion if they win but that is up to the storyteller. Specters would also attack the player.

You could change the dots to angst if you wanted to.

**Vampires**

Since the sea of sorrows is described as being "cold fire" you could reasonably justify running it as either cold damage or fire damage. I personally would use cold so that wraiths would fall faster than vampires. If you wanted to include mental damage I would subtract 2 from rolls to resist raging. Specters would still try to attack.

Comment: The Third Maelstrom is the event that turns the Sea of Shadows into the violent, roiling Tempest. Before that point, why would it do aggravated damage?

Comment: The sea of shadows is made of wraiths I imagine that it would take a large amount of focus to maintain your body without becoming part of the sea. If you don't want to include the damage you can always throw it out.